# How to add inline submenus like the screenshot

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, submenu

i have added logo and man menu using bootstrap3

But how to add submenus like the screenshot using bootstrap3.

If it is better way to display the submenu, please.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/unU9I.jpg

Comment: Where is the screenshot? If you can add the code that you tried we could help you.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap has nav-tabs that work great for this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="h1">Heading</div>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
      <li class="active"><a href="">Submenu 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Submenu 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Submenu 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  <br />
  <div class="tab-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
</div>
```

Example here: http://www.bootply.com/gViQEKnTfZ

Also, remove `class="active"` from the first tab to get closer to your specific styling, if you feel the need.